# UIView animateWithDuration causes app to crash

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, segmentation-fault

My snippet of code is given below. This causes the app to crash. Curiously, the app only crashes when I create an archive and load the archive on my device. If I run it on the device straight from XCode, it runs fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:((j+1) * 10 + (i+1))];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                             label.alpha = 0.0f;
                             label.text = [cryptograms objectAtIndex:i * 12 + j];
                             label.alpha = 1.0f;
                         }];
    }
}
```

If I however, create an archive using the following code snippet, it works fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:((j+1) * 10 + (i+1))];
        [label setText:[cryptograms objectAtIndex:i * 12 + j]];

    }
}
```

I have verified that the problem is not the size of the array. The array always has 96 elements. The crash log shows the following..

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000017
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37148584 _cache_getImp + 4
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37148fa0 lookUpMethod + 24
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3714a1e2 class_respondsToSelector + 26
3   CoreFoundation                  0x382c3638 ___forwarding___ + 372
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3821b204 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20
5   GridSoftToken                   0x000990ae __41-[ViewController updateCryptogramLabels:]_block_invoke_0 (ViewController.m:69)
6   UIKit                           0x375bae80 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:animations:start:completion:] + 492
7   UIKit                           0x37672172 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) animateWithDuration:animations:] + 54
8   GridSoftToken                   0x0009903c -[ViewController updateCryptogramLabels:] (ViewController.m:66)
9   GridSoftToken                   0x00098dc2 -[ViewController viewDidAppear:] (ViewController.m:44)
10  UIKit                           0x3760b2c8 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 132
11  UIKit                           0x37627f24 -[UIViewController _executeAfterAppearanceBlock] + 48
```

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot this issue ? I can obviously get rid of the animation, but I would like to keep it in place.

Comment: Forgot to mention.. not sure if it matters, but I am running iOS6 on iPhone 5

Answer (score 1):

**1:** Put your logic **inside** the animation block and not vice versa.

`SIGSEV` means that your program tries to read or write outside the memory that is allocated for it. It's hard for me to see the reason for it in your code. I could be something with the tags or the scope of the animation gets somehow mixed up since you creating a lot of simultaneous animations.

**2:** Your alpha change code...

```
label.alpha = 0.0f;
label.alpha = 1.0f;
```

... won't have any affect since you change the alpha in the same animation.
If you wan't to set it back to 1.0f then do that in the *completion* block.

Comment: On pt 2, The animation works fine when I run it from XCode; the desired effect is that the labels blink and they all blink perfectly. Only when I convert it into an archive does the SIGSEGV happen!! And on pt 1, I'll try putting logic inside and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using @yinkou's suggestion of putting the logic within the animation block, I re-worked the code and now it runs without any issues.Attaching the revised code below for reference. Hopefully it will help somebody else.
I am still not sure why this works and the previous version does not, but like @yinkou suggested, maybe it has something to do with the large number of simultaneous animations!!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                         for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                             UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:((j+1) * 10 + (i+1))];
                             [label setAlpha:0.0f];
                             [label setText:[cryptograms objectAtIndex:i * 12 + j]];
                             [label setAlpha:1.0f];
                         }
                     }
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if (finished) {
                         ...
                     }
                 }];
```